# How To Set as COM2 to a Device?

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, serial-port

My application using two devices: card reader and Self Service Passbook Printer (SSPP), now both of them using serial port COM1, so now I can only test my application with card reader only or SSPP only.

How to make the SSPP = COM1, and card reader = COM2? so I can use both devices in my application. Im using Csharp.

Regards,
Imam

Comment: How many physical com ports are on your computer?

Comment: You'll have to pay a visit to the serial port store and buy another one.

Comment: I have 6: COM1, COM2,...COM6, when I run my application, both card reader and SSPP using COM1. I should turn off one of them if I use it.

Comment: In the back of my CPU, I have 2 serial ports, but both of them using COM1, right now I must turn of one of my device if I want to use it in my application (between SSPP and card reader) >.<

Comment: Is the different serial port will always get different COM (COM1 or COM2)? In my situation, both using COM1 :)

Answer (score 1):

You can remap COM ports using some Virtual Serial Port driver, like this one.

http://www.eltima.com/products/vspdxp/

or this

http://www.virtual-serial-port.com/virtual-serial-port-kit.html

Windows itself also provides some limited ways to change COM port number in its Device Manager.

The official HowTo: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/232673

Comment: How to see what device on COM1, COM2, etc in Device Manager? I only see the list of COM1, COM2, etc without the device connected to them, Let me see the link, thank you very much ^^

Comment: Here you go:  http://www.sealevel.com/support/article/AA-00441/154/Resource-Center/Serial-Interfaces/How-to-change-asynchronous-serial-COM-port-assignments-in-Windows-Device-Manager.html

Comment: To see what is the device attached to the port I guess you might try to use the official tools for each device: i.e., run the device configurator and probe each port.